# Parsing a http Post request using ctor, <$

Tags: haskell

```
-- file: ch16/HttpRequestParser.hs
p_request :: CharParser () HttpRequest
p_request = q "GET" Get (pure Nothing)
        <|> q "POST" Post (Just <$> many anyChar)
  where q name ctor body = liftM4 HttpRequest req url p_headers body
            where req = ctor <$ string name <* char ' '
        url = optional (char '/') *>
              manyTill notEOL (try $ string " HTTP/1." <* oneOf "01")
              <* crlf
```

The above [snippet](https://github.com/cyga/real-world-haskell/blob/master/ch16/HttpRequestParser.hs#L26) is meant for parsing a http request..

variable `ctor` is seen on the left side and the right side,

```
q name ctor body = liftM4 HttpRequest req url p_headers body  --- ctor assigned a value
       where req = ctor <$ string name <* char ' '            --- ctor used as a function
```

And the variable `name` is as well seen on LHS and RHS.

And `<$>` maps all list elements to a constant value. In this context,

```
ctor <$ string name <* char ' '
```

what does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific examples of the expression `ctor <$ string name <* char ' '` are:

```
Get <$ string "GET" <* char ' '
```

and

```
Post <$ string "POST" <* char ' '
```

`Get` and `Post` are constructors for the GET and POST HTTP verbs. They probably come from a data definition like:

```
data HttpVerb = Get | Post | Head | ...
```

The `<$` operator is defined to be `fmap . const` (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36-)) and has type:

```
<$ :: a -> f b -> f a
```

In other words, it simply wraps up `a` in the functor but after evaluating its second argument `f b`. Note that you normally see `<$>` used here and that the value `b` is ignored. The absence of the `>` in the operator serves to indicate that the value to the right is ignored. Similarly for the `<*` operator.

So, the parser computation `Get <$ string "GET" <* char ' '` returns `f Get` (where `f` is the parser functor) but only if `string "GET"` and `char ' '` succeed.

The equivalent monadic expression is:

```
do string "GET"; char ' '; return Get
```